# flexislider is not working on site, images are not rotated but nav dots are changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Here http://www.outdoorcoverdepot.com/, I put the flexislider but it is not working. Even I put the demo code as it was, but still it is not working.

Even there is no js error coming, what is happening, iages are not changing but navigation dots in bottom are changing as it should be.

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({ ????

Comment: did not get your point
I called this using below
$('#flexcarousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 188,
    //itemMargin: 5 ,
    asNavFor: '#flexslider'
  });

Comment: i asked as i don't see jquery.flexslider-min.js

Comment: it is in the shop.js file in footer.
slider is coming even slider navigation dots in bottom are also moving but images are nt moving

Comment: on my end the bulleted nav is not moving in auto or on click

Comment: it is moving from first to last image but then it stops on last one

Comment: try this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> to this one and let me know <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this
try this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` to this one and let me know

```
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```